# How to improve the look of a math expression with long superscript?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I don't like very much the superscripts, subscripts and comma position in equation (1).

In equation (2) I've made the superscripts and subscripts smaller but still I don't think it is completely good.

Any idea to improve this equation?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{MRC}^{t}=\max\left\{\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{t-1,10}, \, \frac{k}{60}\sum_{i=1}^{60}\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{t-i,10}\right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{MRC}^{t}=\max\left\{\mathrm{VaR}_{\mathsmaller{0.99}}^{\mathstrut  \mathsmaller{t-1,10}}, \, \frac{k}{60}\sum_{i=1}^{60}\mathrm{VaR}_{\mathsmaller{0.99}}^{\mathstrut \mathsmaller{t-i,10}}\right\}
\end{equation}

where MRC is the Market Risk Capital required at time $t$ and $\text{VaR}_{\alpha}^{j,h}$ is the day $j$'s Value at Risk calculated
with a holding period of $h$ trading days and an $\alpha$ confidence level

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never leave a blank line after a math display.

Comment: @greg thank you, JPi has already noted that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some visual adjustments with `\,` in suitable places, to make more room and help parsing the formulas.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{MRC}^{t}=
  \max\biggl\{
    \mathrm{VaR\,}_{\mathstrut 0.99}^{\mathstrut t-1,10}\, , \;
    \frac{k}{60}\sum_{i=1}^{60}\mathrm{VaR\,}_{\mathstrut 0.99}^{\mathstrut t-i,10}
  \biggr\}
\end{equation}
where MRC is the Market Risk Capital required at time $t$ and 
$\mathrm{VaR}_{\alpha}^{j,h}$ is the day $j$'s Value at Risk calculated
with a holding period of $h$ trading days and an $\alpha$ confidence level

\end{document}
```

As you see, the adjustments are not necessary in the inline version, where just symbols are used.

I added a thin space before the comma and a thick space after it, besides `\mathstrut` in the subscripts and superscripts. I also used `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of `\left` and `\right`, in order to make the braces less prominent.

[image]

Comment: Your solution is perfect!

Comment: For consistency, I've put a `\,` even here: `\mathrm{MRC}^{\,t}`

Answer (score 3):

I would not mess with their sizes, but (if doing anything) insert more space between subscript and superscript.  Also, make sure you don't have an empty line after displayed equations to avoid undesirable indentation.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\VaR}{VaR}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{MRC}^{t}=\max\left\{\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{t-1,10}, \, \frac{k}{60}\sum_{i=1}^{60}\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{t-i,10}\right\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{MRC}^{t}=\max\left\{\VaR_{\vphantom{(}0.99}^{\mathstrut  \vphantom{(}t-1,10}, \, \frac{k}{60}\sum_{i=1}^{60}\VaR_{\vphantom{(}0.99}^{\mathstrut \vphantom{(}t-i,10}\right\}
\end{equation}
%
where MRC is the Market Risk Capital required at time $t$ and $\text{VaR}_{\alpha}^{j,h}$ is the day $j$'s Value at Risk calculated
with a holding period of $h$ trading days and an $\alpha$ confidence level

\end{document}.
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\mathstrut  \vphantom{(}`? `\mathstrut` is already defined as  `\vphantom{(}`. Also, `VaR` is an acronym, not a math operator; better write `\newcommand\VaR{\mathrm{VaR}}`.

Comment: The `\mathstrut` was in the original code, albeit combined with `\mathsmaller`.  I did not know that `\mathstrut` was identical to `\vphantom{(}`.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an idea what you might be after. Was it this you were hoping for?

[image]

You see I can do that (obviously), but the only way I know how is, at best, inelegant:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \newlength{\VaRlength}
  \settowidth{\VaRlength}{$\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{t-1,10}$}
  \mathrm{MRC}^{t} =
  \max\left\{\makebox[\VaRlength][l]{$\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{\mathrlap{%
          t-1,10}},$} \,
    \frac{k}{60}\sum_{i = 1}^{60}\mathrm{VaR}_{0.99}^{t-i,10}\right\}
\end{equation}
where MRC is the Market Risk Capital required at time $t$ and
$\text{VaR}_{\alpha}^{j,h}$ is the day $j$'s Value at Risk calculated
with a holding period of $h$ trading days and an $\alpha$ confidence
level

\end{document}
```

Still, for what it's worth...

Comment: I prefer JPi's solution, but I'll try if some combination of the two is good, however thank you.